# NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER in MySQL 8.0

Tags: mysql

when ever i tried to import dumpfile in command prompt then i'm getting this error.

> variable sql_mode can't be set to the value of no_auto_create_user in MySQL 8.0

Answer (score 5):

In the MySQL docs for 5.7 is:

> Previously, **before NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER was deprecated**, one reason not
> to enable it was that it was not replication safe. Now it can be
> enabled and replication-safe user management performed with CREATE
> USER IF NOT EXISTS, DROP USER IF EXISTS, and ALTER USER IF EXISTS
> rather than GRANT. These statements enable safe replication when
> replicas may have different grants than those on the source.

(source: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/sql-mode.html#sqlmode_no_auto_create_user )

The setting `NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER` does not exist anymore in 8.0.

In the release notes for 8.0.11 is the following text:

> The following features related to account management have been
> removed:
>
> Using GRANT to create users. Instead, use CREATE USER. Following this
> practice makes the NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER SQL mode immaterial for GRANT
> statements, so it too is removed.

(source: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/relnotes/mysql/8.0/en/news-8-0-11.html )